# Rails: How to conditionally require a form's field based on which submission button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm working on a form with HAML and Rails.  I'm adding a 'Save as Draft' button in addition to the usual 'Submit' button, but need some of the fields to only be required when submitting.  How do I make the 'form.input... required:' attribute conditional based on whether the user has clicked to submit or to save as a draft? Partial HAML code:

```
= form.input :title, example: t('.example.title'), maxlength: 50, required: true

%button.pull-left.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg{type: 'submit'}= t('.save')
%button.btn.btn-lg{type: 'draft'}= t('.draft')
```

Partial controller code after form is submitted:

```
def create
if params[:submit]
  submit_proposal
elsif params[:draft]
  save_draft
...
```

However, attempting to add the conditional in this controller area would be too late, as the form will already have disallowed the submission with a "This field is required." message next to the field.

Comment: post your code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious answer would be to not require the ones that are only required on submit and then check if they're present when the user does submit.
The more complicated way would be to use 2 different endpoints for the 2 functions and have one require all the parameters and one a subset.
Yet more complicated would be to accept a subset of parameters and then add custom javascript to check if it's submit or save draft and only proceed with the submit if all are present.